# Mysql MYISAM force operating on a crashed database

Tags: mysql, myisam, corruption

Is theres a way to forcibly operate on a database that crashed (even if it's not possible through mysql cli at least a way to remove the dirty bit that marks it as crashed by editing with an editor).

Database corruption is not a problem for me I just want to make database working again, regenerating MYI file is not possible because of extremely large database that weights around 100gb and system lacks resources to recover it (It would take an eternity).

There are backups too that will take weeks to restore it, "crash" happened because INDEX Creation was interrupted because of power outage there shouldn't be anything lost significantly because it was almost done and missing a few megabytes of data shouldn't affect normal operation. Contents of data isn't super duper important, data is primarily used for statistics so missing a few megs of data wouldn't affect statistics significantly.

I just want a way to unmark the crashed bit thanks.

Comment: If the contents of the data isn't important as you say, then just delete it and start over.

Comment: Data is important but losing small quanity is not since this is for statistics and dataset is pretty large losing a few thousands (maybe even millions) of records is acceptable because it wouldn't affect the outcome significantly problem is not being able to access the database and backups would take very long to restore, what has to be done is unmark crashed bit and I want to know if it's possible. If it's large enough from start it is guaranteed to be large at end.

Comment: I don't know of any such option. MyISAM tables are susceptible to corruption, and for this reason, I haven't used them in 10+ years.

Comment: Maybe this might help https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/12/mysqlcheck/

Answer (score 0):

See the options on `REPAIR TABLE`.

This should be a wake up call to switch to InnoDB.

Answer (score 0):

I understand the urgency of accessing your database
Some options to try are:

1. REPAIR TABLE command: MySQL offers this with various recovery levels but there might be data loss.
2. MyISAMchk recovery (use with caution): This utility can also attempt recovery, but again, data loss is a possibility.

Always back up your MyISAM files before using either option. Consider the impact of data loss before proceeding.

If a small amount of data loss is acceptable, you can use the existing data and recreate the missing index. But, analyze the missing data's impact on statistics before proceeding. Remember, weigh the potential data loss against the time it takes to restore from backups.